# How to repeat redundant combinations using the `combn` function in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  letter = letters[1:4]
)
```

I am running the `combn` function on this dataframe:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(
    combo = combn(df1$letter, 2, stringr::str_c, collapse = '_')
  )
```

Which gives this:

```
combo
a_b
a_c
a_d
b_c
b_d
c_d
```

However, the way that I am subsequently wrangling the data requires me to list *all* combinations despite repetitions. The `combn` function seems to drop the repeated groups. That said, I'd like my result to look like this:

```
combo
a_b
a_c
a_d
b_a
b_c
b_d
c_a
c_b
c_d
d_a
d_b
d_c
```

Is there a workaround that I can use to achieve this result? I am open to using something other than `combn` if there's a better way to make this work.

Comment: do not use `$` inside the dplyr verbs, unless otherwise specified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tidy solution:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  letter = letters[1:4],
  letter1 = letters[1:4]
)

purrr::cross_df(df1) %>%
  dplyr::filter(letter != letter1) %>%
  tidyr::unite(combo, c(letter1, letter), sep = "_")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are three solutions with package `arrangements`.

**1.** Without a pipe

```r
a <- arrangements::permutations(letters[1:4], 2)
data.frame(combo = apply(a, 1, paste, collapse = "_"))
#>    combo
#> 1    a_b
#> 2    a_c
#> 3    a_d
#> 4    b_a
#> 5    b_c
#> 6    b_d
#> 7    c_a
#> 8    c_b
#> 9    c_d
#> 10   d_a
#> 11   d_b
#> 12   d_c
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**2.** With a pipe

Except for package `permutations` all other functions are base functions. Output omitted.

```r
letters[1:4] |>
  arrangements::permutations(2) |>
  apply(1, paste, collapse = "_") |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  `names<-`('combo')
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**3.** With a pipe

A pipe plus `tidyverse` functions. Output omitted.

```r
letters[1:4] |>
  arrangements::permutations(2) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    combo = stringr::str_c(V1, V2, sep = '_')
  ) |>
  dplyr::select(-V1, -V2)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>